# What's the right way of combining CSS multiple pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have created a code for a page following Stackoverflow answers. It works very well, but I'd like to optimize it, which I do not know since I'm not a programmer. What is the right way?

```
#black:before {
content: ""; 
position: fixed;
top: 0; 
right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; background: none; 
z-index: -2;}

#red:before {
content: ""; 
position: fixed;
top: 0; 
right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; background: none; 
z-index: -2;}

 #black:target::before {background: #ACAA92;}
 #red:target::before {background: #ACAA92;}

 #black:hover .text{display:block;} 
 #com:hover .text{display:block;}
```

Comment: "Optimize it" in what way?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to combine all those pseudo-elements in just one line of code. In this example I just put two of each, but in real they are 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All selectors which should share the same properties and values can simply be comma separated. You can write them all on one line though a more preferred style is to put each one its own line to aid readability:

```
#black:target::before, #red:target::before { background: #ACAA92; }

#black:hover .text,
#com:hover .text {
  display:block;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Groups_of_selectors_on_one_rule

Comment: You forgot the ID `#`s.